# How to pull inventory in Openstack

Tags: openstack

Is there anyway to pull a complete inventory of servers in Openstack?  I know that I can pull something in Keystone, but I don't think that will give me hostnames.  Either Horizon or CLI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Horizon GUI would probably be one option to provide you with an inventory of your compute resources. If you want bare metal information, MAAS can provide an inventory list.